# Git workflow for libraries being used "inplace"

Tags: git, github

I have some library installed directly from github (in my case the modular-boost superproject). When I want to change things, I want to: fork the master branch on github, switch in place to my fork, change, test, commit to my fork, push to my fork, send pull-request, keep my fork up-to-date with master till my pull-request is accepted, delete my fork and switch back to origin master.

So:

1. I fork the library repository in github
2. I add my fork as a new remote to my local copy of the `origin` repository with `git remote add name git@github.com:user/libname.git`
3. I pull from my remote to check that everything is fine, no changes.
4. I make some changes and `git add -u; git commit -m "..."`
5. I get: `[detached HEAD 7fcasdb0] ...` why?
6. If I try to push to my fork, I get everything is up-to-date.

What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Comments for your steps:

1. I fork the library repository in github (ok)
2. I add my fork as a new remote to my local copy of the `origin` repository with `git remote add name git@github.com:user/libname.git`  (ok)
3. I pull from my remote to check that everything is fine, no changes. (fine, no changes will be download if your local repo is already up-to-date)
4. I make some changes and `git add -u; git commit -m "..."` (did you execute `git checkout name/master` before you do `git add` and `git commit`? if so, you will be in `detached HEAD` mode after commit)
5. I get: `[detached HEAD 7fcasdb0] ...` why? (generally speaking, you get `detached HEAD` mode when `HEAD` point to a commit directly. start work directly upon a remote branch is not recommended since remote branch can not be changed locally. create a new local branch starting from a remote branch and commit your work upon this local branch)
6. If I try to push to my fork, I get everything is up-to-date (you can not push your work with default arguments under `detached HEAD` mode)

## Recommended steps:

1. fork in github
2. add remote repo to local copy of the `origin` repo
3. `git pull my-fork-repo` for downloading remote branch
4. `git checkout -b my-enhance my-fork-repo/master` for creating a local branch
5. change, test, commit your enhancement
6. `git push my-fork-repo my-enhance` for pushing your local branch to your fork repo on github